# UMP test for geometric distribution at $\alpha=0.05$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, neyman-pearson-lemma

Let the pmf of a population $X$ be $P$($X=k$)=$p^k(1-p)$ with $0<p<1$. We take a sample of size $n=1$. The hypothesis $H_0$ says $p\leq0.95$ and $H_1$ is $p>0.95$. Find a level $\alpha=0.05$ UMP hypothesis test.

I have figured out the rejection region, which is, for $x\geq19$, when $\frac{0.95x^x}{(x+1)^{x+1}}>c$ for some prescribed c. However I am having troubles turning this rejection region into something useful in order to find the $\alpha=0.05$ UMP test.

Comment: Because this is a homework/self-study question, you should add the `self-study` tag to your question. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've already shown that this family has a monotone likelihood ratio, and that the UMP test should reject for large $X$.

Then what you want to do is identify the *largest* rejection region of this form so that the probability of rejection when $p = 0.95$ is $0.05$.  Since your test statistic is a discrete random variable, this will likely involve using a randomized test.  So first find the smallest $k \in \mathbb{N}$ for which $P(X \geq k \mid p = 0.95) \leq 0.05$.  (This could be done by brute force using some software.)  Then determine the probability with which you should reject when $X = k - 1$ so that the probability of rejecting is exactly $0.05$, which only requires solving $P(X \geq k \mid p = 0.95) + \tau P(X = k - 1 \mid p = 0.95) = 0.05$ for $\tau$.